# Unity Topology & CS0101

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, user-interface, namespaces

*Hey, so I've stumbled upon this little logistical issue. I can't find any actuall solutions to this specific use case, so I've created this simple example:*

Imagine a simple sketch of a UI element in a game.

[image]

As you can imagine, this panel shows a popup that shows all the rewards and keys needed to unlock the chest.

It consists of multiple elements, and as these elements are repeated, it's a good practice to separate them. So let's say I Separate them into three different Monobehaviour classes, each having its own file.

- TreasurePanelUI: The main panel element that houses references to all non-repeating UI elements.
- Reward: A sub-element of the TreasurePanelUI, it houses references to its own elements (Image of the item, Text reference for the name, etc.)
- Lock: A sub-element of the TreasurePanelUI, it houses references to its own elements (Image of the Lock, effects, animations of unlocking the lock, etc.)

**So here comes the issue, how do we divide their namespaces? Well, here is my idea:**

The dominant TreasurePanelUI may look something like this:

```
namespace UI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public class TreasurePanelUI: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
    }
}
```

And the other two elements may look something like this:

```
namespace UI.TreasurePanelUI //The class is a UI element but also part of TreasurePanelUI.
{
    public class Reward: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace UI.TreasurePanelUI //The class is a UI element but also part of TreasurePanelUI.
{
    public class Lock: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
    }
}
```

Seems logical right? Well, here's **the problem**: It won't compile.
This will throw a [CS0101](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0101?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0101)). Meaning our class name is clashing with the namespace name.

**My main question is, is there an alternative way of achieving the same code topology that will actually compile?**

Also, feel free to point out if my approach or my topology/method is entirely wrong! haha

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use the same names for classes and namespaces, because (like it happened to you) they might clash.

The C# doc comes very *close* to discouraging what you are doing.

> DO NOT use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace.
> For example, do not use Debug as a namespace name and then also provide a class named Debug in the same namespace. Several compilers require such types to be fully qualified.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces)

I would suggest to just put all the classes in the `UI.Treasures` namespace.

Comment: Hey. **You're right to say it's bad practice**, and I wish it wasn't necessary. In an ideal world, I would ditch the namespaces and do what @Chuck suggested and just use a subclass as it makes the most sense, but as I explained to him it won't work because of unity.

**I'd like an alternative solution that lets me mimic a subclass solution, while still being attachable to gameobject.**

Comment: I assume by subclass you actually mean nested class. Could you elaborate on why it is necessary to put your classes in this kind of nested hierarchy instead of just having them next to eachother in the same namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You already got this answer when you asked [this exact same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091680/unity-topology-and-cs0101).

Your code does not run because `UI.TreasurePanelUI` is an ambiguous call - is it the namespace for the other classes or is it the `TreasurePanelUI` class?

Like I told you in your other question - just rename your `TreasurePanelUI` class.

If you're looking for a list of alternatives then I think that's off-topic, but you could make the other classes subclasses of your `TreasurePanelUI` class, like:

```
namespace UI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public class TreasurePanelUI: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
        public class Reward: MonoBehaviour
        {
            //Neat code...
        }
        public class Lock: MonoBehaviour
        {
            //Neat code...
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access `UI.TreasurePanelUI.Reward` or whatever. If you don't want them all in the same file you can use the `partial` class, like:

```
namespace UI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public partial class TreasurePanelUI: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
    }
}
namespace UI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public partial class TreasurePanelUI: MonoBehaviour
    {
        public class Reward: MonoBehaviour
        {
            //Neat code...
        }
    }
}
namespace UI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public partial class TreasurePanelUI: MonoBehaviour
    {
        public class Lock: MonoBehaviour
        {
            //Neat code...
        }
    }
}
```

But really, the best thing you can do it to just change the name of your `TreasurePanelUI` class. If it's a base canvas or base element then you could have

```
namespace UI.TreasurePanelUI //The class is a UI element.
{
    public class BaseCanvas: MonoBehaviour
    {
        //Neat code...
    }
}
```

Comment: *Hey, I've deleted my previous post because it got removed due to a typo I made. But that's beside the point.*


I know renaming solves it. The point of the question was **to find an alternative solution**.  Sorry maybe I should have pointed that out more.

**As to your alternative solution**, subclass/partial won't work because the unity inspector won't recognize it and you'll be unable to attach such a script onto an object. And yes, I did look into these solutions before posting this question. I wish the solution was so simple and clean.

Comment: `And yes, I did look into these solutions before posting this question.` An outline of what you've already tried and why it didn't work is a great thing to put in your question @Mathue24 It gives context and saves me typing all that out so I can just say the following: you must either change the name or make nested classes. There is no other alternative.